# Resetting a timer in Unity

Tags: c#, timer, unity-game-engine

I'm having some issue with my timer I was wondering someone could help me with. I've done a lot of Goggle searches but the main Unity answers site is done for me.

I'm trying to set a timer to start counting up to 10 once I hit an object with a ray. When I no longer hit the object with the ray, I want the timer to stop counting. Should I hit the same object again, I want the timer to start again from the beginning.

What I have at the moment is a timer that only begins when I look at an object. When I look away and the time has got to 3 seconds this is displayed in my Inspector field. But, when I look back at the same object, the time jumps ahead to what ever time has lapsed in between my looking, and not looking at the object.

Can someone please have a look at my logic to see if I'm missing anything?

```
void Start()
{
    start_time = Time.deltaTime;
    running_time = 0;
}

    void Update () 
{

    bool updateTimer = (track_timer && lastHitObject != null);
    Check(updateTimer);
}

// check to see which object my ray has hit
void HighLight(GameObject nextHitObject)
{   
     // Case1: Last ray and new ray both hit objects
    if(lastHitObject != null && nextHitObject != null){

        //1a: same objects, do nothing
        if(lastHitObject.tag == nextHitObject.tag)return;   

        {   //1b: different objects, swap highlight texture
            lastHitObject.renderer.material = oldMat;
            lastHitObject = nextHitObject;
            oldMat = lastHitObject.renderer.material;
            lastHitObject.renderer.material = highlight_material;
            track_timer = true;
            return;
        }
    }

    // Case2: Last ray hit nothing, new ray hit object.
    if(lastHitObject == null && nextHitObject != null){
        ResetTimer();
        lastHitObject = nextHitObject;
        oldMat = lastHitObject.renderer.material;
        lastHitObject.renderer.material = highlight_material;
        track_timer = true;
        return;
    }

    // Case3: Last ray hit something, new ray hit nothing
    if(lastHitObject != null && nextHitObject == null){
        lastHitObject.renderer.material = oldMat;
        lastHitObject = null;
        track_timer = false;

        return;
    }
}



    void ResetTimer()
{
    start_time = 0;
    running_time = 0f;
    //Debug.Log("resetting timer");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted anything that calculates the time you've looked at an item, so I'm not sure what code we're missing in the question.

That said, I suspect the issue is that your `start_time` is always zero (or near zero - it'll initially be set to the time that your `Start` method is called, which will be near zero if it's active immediately).

If you set `start_time = Time.time` in the `ResetTimer` method, then you can calculate how long you've been looking at an object using `Time.time - start_time` - that should be what you're looking for.